# Is there a way to make a null check on a variable in a WHERE clause only occur once?

Tags: sql-server, null

I have a query on a large table that looks like this:

```
declare @myIdParam int = 1

select * 
from myTable
where (@myIdParam is null or myTable.Id = @myIdParam)
```

There are several similar conditionals like this in the where clause, and there are also a lot of joins, but this is a summary.

Effectively, if @myIdParam is null, we do not want to restrict the results using this parameter.

I am not a DB pro, but from my tests it seems like this NULL check is done for every record and not optimized out in any way.

If I remove the null check and assume the parameter is not null, the query returns instantly.  Otherwise, it takes up to ten seconds.

Is there a way to optimize this so the check is done only once at runtime?

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415582/how-can-i-use-optional-parameters-in-a-t-sql-stored-procedure
tl;dr use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`

Comment: @vercelli this does the trick.  Considering this question is really about optional parameters, I'd say it's a duplicate of the one you linked.

Comment: Probably, but it's a post from 6 years ago. Maybe with SqlServer 2014 or 2016 there's a new approach. (I tested it on 2014 without recompile and took forever)

Comment: Since your actual query has many optional parameters, dynamic SQL will provide the best performance.  See http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html for a thorough article on the subject.

Comment: @DanGuzman using WITH RECOMPILE as outlined in the question vercelli linked cut the query time from just under a minute to practically instant with highly selective criteria.  I consider this the best option for balancing performance and readability.

Answer (score 8):

One way is to use dynamic SQL, using a null check to optionally add that part of the where clause.

```
declare @myIdParam int = 1
declare @vc_dynamicsql varchar(max)

set @vc_dynamicsql = 'select * from myTable where 1=1'

if @myIdParam is not null
    set @vc_dynamicsql = @vc_dynamicsql + ' and  myTable.Id = @myIdParam'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @vc_dynamicsql
```

Comment: I would really prefer not to do this, but it is a solution.  My hope is that someone comes along with a much better one.

Comment: This is the best way to handle this class of search query.  The [stackoverflow answer referred to by @vercelli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415582/how-can-i-use-optional-parameters-in-a-t-sql-stored-procedure) contains great references for how to do this.

Comment: This is the best method but I did notice that the @params parameter for `sp_ExecuteSQL` is missing and the `@vc_dynamicsql` parameter needs to be a `NVARCHAR`.

Answer (score 4):

Any time you put a function around a column `ISNULL(@var, table.col)' for example you remove SQL's ability to use an index.  This really is the best performing option if you want to keep it in a single query.

```
@var IS NULL or @var = table.col
```

Otherwise you have two options.  The first is dynamic SQL and @Mystagogue's answer is sufficient for that otherwise you can put in two queries like this:

```
IF @var is NULL
     SELECT * FROM table
ELSE
     SELECT * FROM table WHERE @var = col
```

In both this format and the dynamic SQL you will actually get a different query plan for each of the queries (which will potentially yield better performance).

Comment: The Sql in the question is not using ISNULL or any other function.

Comment: @MystagogueI I was referencing a now deleted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can:

```
declare @myIdParam int = 1;

select *
from myTable
where nullif(@myIdParam, myTable.Id) is null;
```

Keep in mind, however, that the `nullif()` function is essentially a wrapper over `case`. It's not a silver bullet that magickally eliminates `OR` and thus speeds up the query.

Comment: using functions in a where clause has a negative impact on performance because it prevents the use of indexes (or so I've heard)

Comment: @Mystagogue, yes - it usually makes search conditions non-SARGable. Alas, this is the only way I know how to answer your question without resorting to dynamic SQL or multiple `UNION`s. When I had this exact task, I chose dynamic SQL.